# JDBC alternative to show timezone SQL command

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, timezone

Subsequent to my previous question:

[show timezone - difference between pgAdmin and JDBC results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099429/show-timezone-difference-between-pgadmin-and-jdbc-results)

I can connect to a PostgreSQL server in any time zone via pgAdmin and get it to return its time zone via:

```
show timezone;
```

However, if I use JDBC and make the same call, it does not return the time zone text of the external server as expected. It returns the time zone of my client machine, which is not my expected behavior. I expect the same behavior as pgAdmin, that it returns the time zone of the external server as text.

I understand why JDBC would use my client timezone for date-time operations. That makes perfect sense, but when asking an external server for its timezone, then it makes no sense for it to return my client time zone.

I really want to get the time zone of an external server via JDBC without knowing beforehand what that time zone is and having to set the timezone of my JVM manually, as that defeats the point of the call I'm trying to make.

Is there any alternative way to do this, rather than using `show timezone`?

Comment: Please include the code you're using. Without it, readers can only guess what you're doing; code makes it unambiguous.

Comment: Just a thought, could you retrieve `current_timestamp` and `localtimestamp` from the server and subtract? It won’t give you the time zone, I am aware, at best the current offset from UTC.

Comment: What do you need the server’s time zone for? Maybe there’s another way.

Comment: @AlanKrueger I have included the code I'm using. I am using show timezone. And if you need a JDBC example, the see the link to my related question. The code is irrelevant here though. If I use ANY form of JDBC code to call `show timezone` on an external server in a different time zone, it returns my client time zone rather than the expected response.

Comment: "What do you need the server’s time zone for? Maybe there’s another way." - it's not a desperately needed requirement. We manage multiple servers from my office and I I'm using this to check that the timezone has been set correctly in the postgresql setup. Sure, there's alternative ways of doing this, but I was looking for a simple way to ask the external server for its timezone. That's all. Why not? :)

Comment: No, why not? Thanks for explaining. @ManoDestra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time in PostgreSQL is always stored in UTC, the session timezone is what is used for conversion for a connection. This session config can have a default configuration on the server.

If you really need to know it, use

```
select * from pg_file_settings where name = 'timezone'
```

This will only have a value if it is explicitly configured, otherwise the default is GMT.

See also [8.5.3. Time Zones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES):

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They
>   are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone
>   configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

This configuration setting specifies the default session timezone, it is not actually a 'server timezone'); its configuration does not actually have an influence on how PostgreSQL server handles dates in general.

A connection library can override this for a session by specifying the `TimeZone` connection property, or by executing `set time zone '...'` at a later point.

So this is not actually specific to the PostgreSQL JDBC driver: it applies to PostgreSQL in general, but the PostgreSQL JDBC driver always does this (see [`ConnectionFactoryImpl`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/b0cfc33483759ed3583b57cd845311d17670524f/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl.java#L194)) to comply with JDBC specification requirements that dates and times need to be in the default JVM timezone.

Comment: Splendid. Thank you, Mark. Doesn't work for 9.4 databases, but I can definitely work with this, going forward. It (mostly) gives me what I need for the 9.6 databases we manage though. Most of them have been upgraded to 9.6 now anyway with the rest to follow. It returns what I expect now. Some of them are set to "localtime", so are not explicitly returning their actual time zone as such, but I can live with that as that is still a valid response for me. I appreciate your time and effort here. I do understand the restrictions via JDBC and its session. Your solution bridges the gap. Kudos :)